# Unable to get the object using typescript in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript, my Objective is to get the object and represent in UI, but i'm getting the object as

```
{
name: "ABC",
age: 5
}

I'm getting error in this way ***Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'*** 

Can anyone please help me in this query?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to be more specific in defining types.

```
interface State {
  data: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if i have 4 different objects with same property then how could we assign for them. Do we need to assign like this for 4 objects? if no then please assist me

Comment: Yes, or you can define a parent interface and inherit it from others.